# ActionScript - Passing Rest Type Coercion Failed?

Tags: actionscript-3, rest, parameter-passing

i have no idea why the following code doesn't work.

i'm simply passing and then repassing Shape objects as a rest parameter.  when the objects arrive at the final function, they trace as [object Shape], but then on the next line i receive a type coercion failure, stating it couldn't be converted into a Shape.

output:

```
[object Shape],[object Shape]
TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert []@27b68921 to flash.display.Shape.
    at Test/receiver()
    at Test/passer()
    at Test()
```

code:

```
package
{   
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.Shape;

public class Test extends Sprite
    {
    public function Test()
        {
        //Create Shapes
        var myFirstShape:Shape = new Shape();
        myFirstShape.graphics.beginFill(0);
        myFirstShape.graphics.drawRoundRect(0, 0, 100, 100, 50);

        var mySecondShape:Shape = new Shape();
        mySecondShape.graphics.beginFill(0);
        mySecondShape.graphics.drawRoundRect(0, 0, 100, 100, 50);

        //Pass Shapes
        passer(myFirstShape, mySecondShape);
        }

    private function passer(...items):void
        {
        //Pass Shapes Again
        receiver(items);
        }

    private function receiver(...items):void
        {
        //Rest Trace As [object Shape], [object Shape]
        trace(items);

        //Type Coercion Failed ??!!
        for each    (var element:Shape in items)
                    {
                    trace(element);
                    }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit counter intuitive at first sight, but it actually makes sense...

When you declare a rest parameter, the arguments that you actually pass are wrapped in an Array at runtime.

That means, if you do:

```
myFunction(1,2,3);
```

Your function will receive an Array with 3 values.

This is exactly what's going on here:

```
private function passer(...items):void
    {
    //Pass Shapes Again
    receiver(items);
    }
```

`ìtems` is itself an Array in the body of `passer`. But when you call `receiver`, this Array that contains 2 shapes is wrapped in another Array, because you declared that `receiver` took a rest parameter.

When your loop in `receiver` tries to convert each item into a Shape, it fails (because you can't convert an `Array` into a `Shape`).

You could see this changing your code a bit:

```
private function receiver(...items):void
    {
    //Rest Trace As [object Shape], [object Shape]
    trace(items);
    trace(items.length);// --> traces 1
    trace(items[0].length);// --> traces 2; this is the Array you want.

}
```

So, you have a couple of options to fix this, depending on what you really want to achieve.

1) Have `receiver` "unwrap" the rest parameters to get the inner array. Basically loop thorough `items[0]` instead of `items`.

2) Change you function signature to:

```
private function receiver(items:Array):void
```

3) Change the way you call receiver so the array is passed as a list of arguments:

```
    private function passer(...items):void
    {
    //Pass Shapes Again
    receiver.apply(this,items);
    }
```

The effect of this would be equivalent to doing this:

```
receiver(items[0],items[1]);
```

Except it handles the list of items dynamically, of course.

If you really need `passer` to take a rest parameter, you could go with option 3). Otherwise, I'd choose Option 2). Option 1) is the one I like the least, as it's the most brittle, but it's also a valid option.